# Why should I want a larger Feed Bag?

Tags: palworld

One of the "Ancient Technologies" is a Feed Bag which allows you to put food in a special slot so you and your pals can eat it when hungry. This sounds good, at least I don't have to actively go to the menu to stuff my face when I'm starving. There are larger feed bags that allow you to store more different types of food.

But why should I care about getting a bigger bag?

Considering we can have practically infinitely large stacks, I could just carry around a couple thousand berries in one slot and that should keep me satiated. I see no benefit to carrying other types since all they do really is feed you when hungry. For the foods that have other buffs, you'd want to trigger that manually rather than only when hungry.

Comment: ... It frees up an inventory slot? Or 5?

Comment: Not an answer cause I've only been using the small, but a possible reason could be overfeeding. Late-game Pals can have much larger stomachs, and feed bags only work when food levels drop below 50%. So maybe you have something that fills for 100 (number pulled from air), you don't want a Lamball eating that and wasting half the food. 
However, I have no idea if Pals will eat more filling foods if there are multiple types available, or if they only eat the first in the list.

Comment: @FinAndTonic When it comes to choices of food, I think there's no logic to it and only the first food item (from left to right) is eaten. This definitely applied to the Feed Box but haven't verified if it applies to the Feed Bag as well.